# Creating a Datadog monitor with exception message

Tags: datadog

i have created a Datadog Metric monitor for a requirement , if there is any specific error messages thrown( say : value cant be null.) in the stack dump. i need to  alert and  trigger this monitor and let it send mail to the group of people .
But i dont see an option for doing this in Datadog query filter.
Whats the query filter for creating a monitor for a specific  exception message?
i tried with the below in "Define the metric":

env:prod, trace.aspnet.errors, exceptionmessage:value cant be null,

but the above didnt work.

Also,another question : where exactly, i need to search for error code - eg httpstatus code 500, 400,in the logs?